# Change ActionBar Title style

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android Application using an ActionBar which is changing in every Activity.
I am using a NavDrawer and I want to CENTER and make the text WHITE. This text is the TITLE of the Activity chosen in the NavDrawer

Idioma.java

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ActionBar actionbar=(getActivity()).getActionBar();

// SET ACTIONBAR LOGO
    actionbar.setLogo(R.drawable.iconomenu);
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

// SET ACTIONBAR TITLE
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

// SET ACTIONBAR BACKGROUNDIMAGE
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgactionbar));
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_idioma, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for changing the title color use html as below:

```
actionbar.setTitle(
                Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>"
                        + YOUR_TITLE
                        + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own action bar layout file and use it like such:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_action_bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in .java folder but in my experience ,use in styles.xml for seeing how it can be seeing which choose phone in android studio and it's example for you

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">android:color/red</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```